# Call Gradle task with parameters inside other task

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, ant, task

I have a Gradle task which looks like this (it collects inputs from user and then passes them to the second task):

```kotlin
task A() {
    doFirst {
        ant.input(message: "Version:", addproperty: 'version')
        tasks.b "-Pversion=${ant.properties.version}" //attempt to invoke task B()
    }
}
```

The second task just print the passed variables:

```kotlin
task B() {
    doFirst {
        println "Version: ${version}"
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the task A does not invoke task B. I've tried with *finalizedBy* and *doLast* but I couldn't find a solution how to pass arguments while executing the task inside the other task.
When I execute the task B via command line like:

```kotlin
gradle B -Pversion=1.0.0
```

it works fine, and params are passed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to 'invoke' task B from task A - Gradle tasks are not like functions.

The only way to pass data from one task to another is if

1. the first task saves the variables to a file,
2. then the second task reads the file produced by the first task.

There is [an example in the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#working_with_task_dependencies_in_lazy_properties), which you can adjust to capture user input

```groovy
abstract class Producer extends DefaultTask {
    @OutputFile
    abstract RegularFileProperty getOutputFile()

    @TaskAction
    void produce() {
        // capture user input
        ant.input(message: "Version:", addproperty: 'version')
        String message = ant.properties.version
        // save the user input to a file
        def output = outputFile.get().asFile
        output.text = message
        logger.quiet("Wrote '${message}' to ${output}")
    }
}
```